# Get value of jquery variable to php variable without ajax?

Tags: php, jquery

please see my code here :

my HTML code here :

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
     var myvar = $("#myHeader").html();
     <?php $cattitle = myvar; ?>
     });                     
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myHeader">Hello World!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

anyone have idea for that please.

Comment: Not possible. You will have to use AJAX (or a form submission) as PHP runs on the server and JS on the client. I'd suggest you read the duplicate I mentioned to get a better understanding of the differences between the client and server, as well as the page lifecycle.

Comment: there is a big difference between server-side and client-side programming. You have to use AJAX for this

Comment: Thanks for your reply, in the same page, how can get jquery variable value to php varibale using ajax?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax

Comment: Well in theory it is possible to do without ajax by using form submit or get parameters in a url. But you will need to reload your entire page/load another page.